# "If" ternary with echo(). Parser show me an error

Tags: php

I'm trying to identify my pages (for the menu) using if ternary operator.

```
$page_name = "workers";

($page_name != "home") ? echo "home";
```

So I suppose "home" should appear, but no. Parser show me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Which PHP version is this? The parser should have been "unexpected T_ECHO" usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [ternary syntax](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) is wrong, try this:

```
$page_name = "workers";
echo ($page_name != "home" ? "home" : null);
```